# Programmatically add a view to middle of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout with two views

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <Textview />
</LinearLayout>
```

Through my program, I want to add a third `TextView` between these two existing `TextViews`'.
It was easy to do with a `RelativeLayout` with `layout_below` parameter. How do I do this for `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`LinearLayout.addView(View v, int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29)

The docs are a good place to start with this sort of thing.

Just pass an index to where you want it placed (i.e. 2nd position would be index 1).